# Filter between two dates MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have an incentive table:

```
inc_id  int(11)          
inc_date    date    
inc_projectname     varchar(256)         
inc_amount  varchar(256)         
inc_developer_id    int(11)      
inc_sales_id    int(11)  
inc_developer_amt   varchar(256)    
inc_sales_amt   varchar(256)
```

I am trying to write a sql query to fetch entry of a specific user between two date.The function to do so is:

```
 public function  get_all_incentive_by_id ($userid,$inc_from,$inc_to) {  

        //$result = DB::fetch('select * from incentive_table ORDER BY inc_date ASC;');

        $result = DB::fetch("select * from incentive_table where inc_date > '$inc_from' AND inc_date < '$inc_from' ORDER BY inc_date ASC");


        return $result;
        }
```

**Error:** There is no out put.

**Required:** I want result between two dates from a user id

Comment: `inc_date < '$inc_to'`

Comment: a) What format are `$inc_from` and `$inc_to`? b) What does the static function `fetch()` of the `DB` class return? c) Surely it should `inc_date < '$inc_to'`?

Comment: You are using $inc_from twice, I think it should be inc_date<'$inc_to'

Comment: fetch is my DB class function a extented PDO class.

Comment: how write using between? $result = DB::fetch("select * from incentive_table WHERE  ( inc_date BETWEEN '$inc_from' AND '$inc_to')"); Its seems ok. But how i pass a user id to it i want a specific users data.

Comment: After the ) of between add `AND field_of_user_id='$user_id'`

Comment: And please, for the love of everything holy, make sure your inputs are sanitized/escaped/cleaned before you inject them into your query.

Comment: The PDO class function DB::fetch()  will handle "sanitized/escaped/cleaned"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = DB::fetch("SELECT * FROM incentive_table WHERE inc_date BETWEEN '$inc_from' AND '$inc_to' AND inc_sales_id ='$userid'" ORDER BY inc_date ASC");
```

Comment: now i get corrrected still if u find errors pinpoint that where it occurs

Comment: need to include a filter by userid too

Comment: $result = DB::fetch("select * from incentive_table WHERE  ( inc_date BETWEEN '$inc_from' AND '$inc_to') AND inc_sales_id  ='$userid'");

Comment: it is still FULL OF ERRORS, if you don't know sql, why are you answering, especially that all the answers he needs are up there in the comments. FYI: that's wrong inc_date BETWEEN '$inc_from' AND inc_date